# Check for Windows Updates Remotely Using .Net Core

Tags: c#, .net-core, windows-update

I looked around quite a bit and haven't been able to find a good solution so far. Does anyone have a reference to an article or something similar to this problem to point me in a good direction?

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "remotely" in this context?

Comment: @NetMage So from my machine, I want to be able to remotely connect to a server and have it output if updates or reboots need to be initiated. I am attempting to build a back end service for a front end dashboard.

Comment: So you want to know if Update Installation is pending? Or if Update downloads are available? Or if a restart for updates is needed?

Comment: @NetMage Exactly. I have found ways to do this using WUApi but I need something that can be done in .Net Core to support multiple platforms.

Comment: See this article on using Powershell to see [update statuses](https://gist.github.com/gbraad/463512b065ef1f919e63552138d776bf). See [this article](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/determine-pending-reboot-statuspowershell-style-part-1/)  on if reboots are pending from Powershell via the Registry.